Handling null on any()
Here's my method :
IQueryable<T> GetById<T>(IEnumerable<TagOrIdItem> items)
{
   if (items is null || !items.Any())
   {
       return Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable();
   }
}

I call it from here
GetById<Jobs>(targets.SelectMany(target => target.Jobs)).Select(s => s.Caption).Distinct().ToList();

When targets.Jobs is null, it send to the GetById method an null objet. When the Any() is executed, it throws an NullRefException.

Where is the best place to handle it ? In the GetById method or in the caller ?
In the GetById method, how to handler it correctly ? I can't do a Count() because sonar don't want, and i think that it will result the same.

I tried the try catch block with a nullref exception, but sonar said to chek null instead. But i can't check null because the null is on the any method, and not on the items object


    if (items == null || items == Enumerable.Empty<TagOrIdItem>() || !items.Any())
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable();
    }

Add a null check and validate items as being empty or no Any() in enumerable item Otherwise Null Exception from .Any().

This is not correct. Did you test it?
